# Easly catch page reload in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I need to do something when the browser is closing, so first I need to know that it closes. What I found was:

```
<script>
var closing = true;
$(function () {
  $("a,button[type=submit]").click(function()
    {
      closing=false;
  });
  $(window).on("unload",function(){
      if (closing){...}
    });
  });
</script>
```

It works good/nice/etc but there is one "catch": page reload... When the page is reloaded, it's not any click, so it's treated as "closing"... Is there such an easy way to catch the reload (as for the "click" written above)?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `navigation` object property, there you can find the information page is reloaded(value is equal to `1`) or not:

```
<script>
var closing = true;
var performance = window.performance;
$(function () {
  if((performance.navigation && performance.navigation.type === 1) ||
    performance
      .getEntriesByType('navigation')
      .map((nav) => nav.type)
      .includes('reload')){
        closing = false;
        console.log("reloaded");
  }
  $("a,button[type=submit]").click(function()
    {
      closing = false;
  });
  $(window).on("unload",function(){
      if (closing){
       console.log("closing");
      }
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thx for answer, but that's not for this question. Here, You check the "history", but the "core-event" is "unload" (page closing), so it must be checked/cached before the page is closed (reloaded). I put your code into the "unload" event, but the "history" is not yet created...